# How to bind the custom control template into native control

Tags: c#, android, ios, datatemplate, xamarin.forms

I have created the custom control similar to Multiselect list box, I have the template property in that I need to bind Template into native control list,

```
<local:MyList.Template>
   <DataTemplate>
     <Label Text="{Binding Description}" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center"></Label>
   </DataTemplate>
 </local:MyList.Template>
```

I need this label datatemplate into the native control, in WP we have template, hence I can easily binding with the native control. But i can't get it forAndroid and iOS. for xamarin forms.

The question is "How to bind the custom control template into native control"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As example, here is my item creation code for an ItemsView I made modelled after the MS Xaml ItemsControl. It's fairly basic but gets the job done for what I need.

```
View CreateNewItem(object context)
{
var view = this.ItemTemplate.CreateContent() as View;
view.BindingContext = context;
return view;
}
```